# How to call a Javascript method on info() / error() method of Wicket FeedbackPanel?

Tags: javascript, java, wicket

How can I call a JavaScript method from Wicket feedback panel methods such as `info()` and `error()`.

What I am trying to do is, display [MDL](https://getmdl.io/)'s [snackbar](https://getmdl.io/components/index.html#snackbar-section) for Wicket `FeddbackPanel`'s `error()` / `info()` methods. But to show the snackbar, we have to call a JavaScript method. Which I don't know how to do, especially in non-ajax calls.

Answer (score 2):

You could subclass FeedbackPanel and call the javascript in [`renderHead(IHeaderResponse response)`](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.x/org/apache/wicket/Component.html#renderHead(org.apache.wicket.markup.head.IHeaderResponse))

Like this:

```
   @Override
   public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse response) {
      super.renderHead(response);
      response.render(OnDomReadyHeaderItem.forScript("callFancyJs();"));
   }
```

This would call the javascript regardless of AJAX or not.

Additionally if you need to access the `FeedbackMessage`s by it's type in javascript i've added them CSS classes, which i use for [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) styling:

```
   @Override
   protected Component newMessageDisplayComponent(String id, FeedbackMessage message) {
      Component c = super.newMessageDisplayComponent(id, message);
      c.setEscapeModelStrings(false);
      String bootstrapClass = "text-info";
      switch (message.getLevel()) {
         case FeedbackMessage.ERROR:
            bootstrapClass = "text-danger";
            break;
         case FeedbackMessage.WARNING:
            bootstrapClass = "text-warning";
            break;
         case FeedbackMessage.SUCCESS:
            bootstrapClass = "text-success";
            break;
         case FeedbackMessage.FATAL:
            bootstrapClass = "text-danger";
            break;
         case FeedbackMessage.DEBUG:
            bootstrapClass = "text-danger";
            break;
         case FeedbackMessage.INFO:
            bootstrapClass = "text-info";
            break;
      }
      c.add(new AttributeAppender("class", bootstrapClass));
      return c;
   }
```

You could use this classes to target the feedback messages in your javascript.

Answer (score 0):

you have to do this via AJAX request which is handled on server-side and this handler must call the method and after that, add the panel to `AjaxRequestTarget` for being updated

Comment: How to call the JS function from `AjaxRequestTarget`?

Comment: it is not JS function, `AjaxRequestTarget` is Java object - look into wicket tutorials, how to work with AJAX

Comment: I know `AjaxRequestTarget` is a Java object but, my question is how call my JavScript function with that object?

Comment: @SoumitriPattnaik AjaxRequestTarget has a method appendJavascript where you can directly write javascript that will get added as part of the ajax response. But i'm not sure if that is what you really want. Can you describe what you are trying to do? Do you want to execute a javascript if your FeedbackPanel has any info messages and another if it has error messages?

Comment: ah, so how @SoumitriPattnaik said, appendJavascript to the `AjaxRequestTarget`. `ajaxRequestTarget.appendJavascript(";functionCall();");`

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS I have updated the question with more details. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Specifically non-ajax way.

Answer (score 0):

You can take an inspiration from WicketStuff JGrowl integration: https://github.com/wicketstuff/core/tree/master/jquery-parent/jquery/src/main/java/org/wicketstuff/jquery/jgrowl

The way it does it to render a `<script>` for each message. This script has text like `$.jgrowl({...})`.